# How to call MySQL view in Struts2 or Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I have a view in MySQL database

```
CREATE VIEW CustInfo  
AS  
SELECT a.custName,  
a.custMobile,  
b.profession,  
b.companyName,  
b.annualIncome  
FROM customer a  
INNER JOIN cust_proffessional_info b  
ON a.cust_id=b.cust_id
```

Is there any way that i can call this view using Struts2 or in Hibernate.
I have tried to search it but could not find any solution on it.  Could any one please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create an Entity, that's mapping the database view:

```
@Entity
public class CustInfo {

    private String custMobile;
    private String profession;  
    private String companyName;
    private Double annualIncome;  
}
```

Make sure you include an `@Id` in your view as well, if that's an updatable view.

Then you can simply use it like any other Entity:

```
Session session = sessFactory.openSession();
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("from CustInfo");
List<CustInfo> custInfos = (List<CustInfo>) query.list();
```

Comment: your &  Sarfaraz answer helped me to do this. Thank you for your answer. My Problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

You can work with a view as if it is a regular table. Define an entity class, either with the @Entity annotation or an equivalent XML mapping and proceed with it like you do with regular tables. If you need help on how to do these mapping and other things you can simple check any hibernate tutorial for this.

Comment: your & Vlad Mihalcea answer helped me to do this. Thank you for your answer. My Problem is solved.